# FB.api response callback async popup blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
// this is async
//other logic goes here
window.open(mylink + response.name);
}
```

The async problem make me can't do procedure programming style, so I put my code within the block, it got blocked by popup blocker. How to resolve this issue? I googled and people said it can be make async false.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open a popup in an asynchronous callback function, you always have to open it directly on user interaction. This is an important browser feature to protect the user from unwanted popups.

You definitely have to call FB.api BEFORE the user click. Should be no problem to call `FB.api('/me')` right after initializing the JavaScript SDK and store it in a variable for later.